# Problem with query in MySql

Tags: java, mysql

```
String sql = "SELECT siteapplications.Application, Count(visits.VisitId) AS CountOfVisitId 
FROM visits, siteapplications 
WHERE visits.SiteApplicationId=siteapplications.ApplicationID 
and Month(visits.VisitTime)=" + month + " 
and Year(visits.VisitTime)=" + year + 
"GROUP BY siteapplications.Application 
ORDER BY CountOfVisitId DESC;";
rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
```

When I run it I get this error in java :

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BY Application ORDER BY CountOfVisitId DESC' at line 1

I don't see a error ...

Can anyone help ...

thx all

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
" and Year(visits.VisitTime)=" + year + "GROUP BY ...
```

Should be:

```
" and Year(visits.VisitTime)=" + year + " GROUP BY ...
```

Your version is missing a space before `GROUP`.